# Rich snippet is not showing for http://purl.org/goodrelations/

Tags: html, google-rich-snippets, rdfa

My site is https://www.liteshop.com.au/content/olight-h15s-wave-rechargeable-led-headlamp

We implemented rich snippets on my site seven weeks ago but still Google does not show on search. Testing tool shows "All good".

Here is the rich snippets markup:

```html
<div prefix="gr: http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1# v: http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" resource="#gr-ProductOrService" typeof="gr:ProductOrService">
    <span property="gr:name" content="Olight H15S Wave 250 lumen rechargeable LED headlamp"></span>
    <span property="gr:brand" content="Olight"></span>
    <span property="gr:image" content="https://www.liteshop.com.au/sites/default/files/olight_h15s_led_headlamp_01.jpg" ></span>
    <span property="gr:description" content="98g, 250 lumens: The H15S Wave is a powerful and intelligent head lamp with a rechargeable battery pack and infrared sensor for hands free operation.  With 250 lumens of white light, three brightness levels and up to 36 hours of run time, it’s the perfect choice for any challenge you might face in the outdoors. Battery and USB charger included. Can also use 4 X AAA."></span>
    <span property="gr:sku" content="Olight H15S"></span>
    <span property="gr:url" content="https://www.liteshop.com.au/content/olight-h15s-wave-rechargeable-led-headlamp"></span>
    <span property="gr:availability" content="In Stock"></span>
    <span property="gr:hasPriceSpecification" typeof="gr:UnitPriceSpecification">
        <span property="gr:hasCurrencyValue" content="69.95"></span>
        <span property="gr:hasCurrency" content="AUD"></span>
    </span>
    <span property="v:hasReview" typeof="v:Review-aggregate" >
        <span property="v:itemReviewed" content="Olight H15S Wave 250 lumen rechargeable LED headlamp" ></span>
        <span property="v:rating" content="5" ></span> <span property="v:votes" content="2" ></span>
    </span>
    <span property="v:aggregateRating" typeof="v:AggregateRating" >
        <span property="v:reviewCount" content="3" ></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

According to http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Quickstart 'xml:lang="en"' is required for name or description property. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the vocabularies **GoodRelations** and **Data-Vocabulary.org**.

According to [Google’s technical guidelines for structured data](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies#technical_guidelines), they support only¹ the vocabulary **Schema.org**:

> Structured data should be expressed using the most specific applicable type and property names defined by schema.org.

¹ Data-Vocabulary.org was used for their Rich Snippets before; I don’t know if they still support it, but it seems that they don’t document it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

@unor is correct and your syntax is correct. If you changed to schema.org, you would encounter another problem. Google will not accept content=" ". The value for content must be in the clear, i.e `term">content_value</term"`.