# Offers in Products (schema.org / rich snippets)

Tags: schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets

I try to optimize the microdata/ schema.org/ rich snippet markup for product pages within some templates we use.

While doing so placed **itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"** within a **itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product"**

Which should work according to

- https://schema.org/offers

as well as

- https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products

but fails to validate on [Google's Structured Data testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)

Can someone give me some insight on which of the information I should focus?
The 'Offer' delivers some interesting properties I really would like to use within products.

Same goes for **isRelatedTo** which is mentioned on schema.org but fails to validate.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Product` type and the `offers`¹ property from the vocabulary Data-Vocabulary.org, and the `Offer` type from the vocabulary Schema.org. (¹ I don’t know if Data-Vocabulary.org really defined an `offers` property; most of their site seems to be deleted.)

If you want Google Search to consume your data, [you’ll want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35134834/1591669) to use the vocabulary Schema.org.

Schema.org also has a type representing products ([`Product`](http://schema.org/Product)) and a property for referencing an `Offer` from a `Product` ([`offers`](http://schema.org/offers)).

In Microdata, this could look like:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  </div>
</article>
```